# Delphi subclasses inheritance

Tags: delphi

When I write a class I know that I can use the inherted keyword so I can inherit the behavior or TObject, such as:

```
type
 TOperation = class(TObject)
   constructor Create(dest, r1, r2: integer);
 end;
```

And the constructor will have an `inherited Create;`. Look at the following class:

```
type
 TAddition = class(TOperation)
   constructor Create(a1, a2: integer);
 end;
```

If the first line of TAddition is `inherited Create;` it means that I am inheriting the behavior of TOperation of course. But does this mean that I am also inheriting the behavior of TObject? (which is a superclass of TOperation).

When I inherit from the constructor of a father class (look at TAddition) I am inheriting only the behaviour, don't I? I am not initializing anything from the father class

The complete code is here:

```
 TOperation = class(TOBject)
  private
   dest, v1, v2: integer;
  public
   constructor Create(dest, r1, r2: integer);
   property destination: integer read dest;
   property value1: integer read v1;
   property value2: integer read v2;
 end;

 TMemoria = class(TOperation )
  private
   dest, r1: integer;
  public
   constructor Create(dest, r1: integer);
   property destination: integer read dest;
   property register1: integer read r1;
 end;

 constructor TOperation.Create(dest, r1, r2: integer);
 begin

  //inherit from TObject
  inherited Create;
  Self.r1 := r1;
  Self.r2 := r2; //so on...

 end;

constructor TMemoria.Create(dest, r1: integer);
 begin

  //inherit from TObject OR inherit from TOperation?
  inherited Create;

 end;
```

Comment: You need to be much clearer. In you lr outline you inherit some behaviour bit not all. You bypass the parent constructor and go straight to the TObject constructor. Describing code leads to confusion. Show it. An mcve.

Comment: Yes, please add the implementation of your creators

Comment: I have added the scenario. My question is basically if the subclass in inheriting from TObject or from the father class

Comment: Well, since `TOperation` does not implement a `Create` constructor, the base class `Create` is called. See [Inheritance and Scope](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Inheritance_and_Scope): *The scope of a member's identifier starts at the point where the member is declared, continues to the end of the class declaration, and extends over all descendants of the class and the blocks of all methods defined in the class and its descendants.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
constructor TMemoria.Create(dest, r1: integer);
begin
  inherited Create;
end;
```

This calls the parameterless constructor in `TObject` and does not call the constructor declared in the immediate ancestor. That much should be clear because no parameters are supplied.

For full details please see the documentation: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Inherited

As a strong guiding principle you should not miss out calling inherited constructors from parent classes. Often this means that you fail to instantiate an object that is used by the parent class. I would regard the code in the question as very suspicious.

Comment: Ok great, that was what I needed to know; even if the TMemoria is a sublcass it inherits from TObject's create. Without the Create what happens?

Comment: Well, it depends which one you call. And if you defined a parameterless constructor in the immediate ancestor, then it would be called.

Comment: Ok so if TOperation had a constructor called only Create, TMemoria would have called the TOperation's constructor (not TObject's constructor)?

Comment: Indeed. This is all documented you know.

Comment: According with your edit, if I called the parent constructor (like the TOperation with his parameters) other than the "inherited Create", I'd have to pass the 3 paramenters. That wouldn't have a sense. Is this what you mean?

Comment: If the parent class needs those parameters, how can the derived class not supply them. That's a massive code smell.